# sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: files, for

This command gives an error "sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

```
for file in /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_*.csv; do echo "Testing" done
```

What is wrong with the above command ?
Thank you

Comment: https://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add ; before done, or put new line here.

```
for file in /dev/DataStage/myProject/source/TEST/MyFile_*.csv; do echo "Testing" ; done
```